# List all existing Flows as options in a Custom Object field

Tags: custom-object, visual-workflow, data, variable

I am working on a project and I want to create a Custom Object that has as a field a lookup for flows.

I would like to know if there is some kind of way to retrieve all existing flows in one org and put them as an option for this field.
Also, if there is a way to filter that field according to another field.

For example: I have two fields, Action Type & Action Name
An Action Type can be either Flow or Apex
According to the filled answer of Action Type, I want to filter the options of Action Name and list all existing flows or all existing apex classes accordingly.

Comment: Metadata API is how you find the flows; it can be called from Apex or from the client

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this is a bit dumb requirement. You can always create 2 picklist, one dependant from another, an enter the values manually. Or retrieve those values via MetadataAPI or SF CLI, process the data retrieved, and deploy picklist values to the org through Metadata API or SF CLI